# Custom EditText: input-box type for for login page

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a sign-in activity. So, I chose the login activity, but the login page looks quite plane. Here's the layout I would like to implement at the login page

[image]

I'm using the following drawable layout for the changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thickness="0dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#C8CAD0"/>
<corners
    android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

I want the common border between the two fields to be merged into a single line of thickness 1dp.

Here's the xml for the two fields - username and password:

```
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="  Username or Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:background="@drawable/box_input_field"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_input_field"
                android:hint=" Password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in this Method is.
Create 2 different drawables for email view and password view.
Show 2 drawables below,
I set **`<item android:top="-1dp">`** in **edittext_bottom_curv_gray.xml** for make middle line thin.

This will look like this =>

[image]

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtUserEmail"
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_curv_gray"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtUserPassword"
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_curv_gray"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Style of EditText **style.xml**

```
<style name="EditTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#9A9A9A</item>
```

**Drawable 1 for email field.**

**edittext_top_curv_gray.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" >
            </stroke>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Drawable 2 for password field.**

**edittext_bottom_curv_gray.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-1dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" >
            </stroke>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. Could do the work, but it would be best if I could have a 1dp wide common-boundary, while the other boundaries being 2dp.

Comment: Wait I will post 2nd method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check and modify according to your needs:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_linear"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/org_editBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_org"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                        android:background="#D3D3D3" />


                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/salesperson_editBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_sales_person"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/orgtype_editBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_org_type"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

rounded_linear.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.3dp"
        android:color="#D3D3D3" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two EditText in a vertical LinearLayout, and set the [divider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:divider) attribute to handle the line inbetween the two fields. You can then set your existing drawable as the LinearLayout bg with no change required.

Answer (score 0):

To make this simple, you could:

- place those edittexts inside a LinearLayout
- Add a simple View between them with the background color (#C8CAD0) and the height with the same value as the stroke (2dp)
- set box_input_field as the LinearLayout background